# Build firebreath plugin with XCode

Tags: xcode, cmake, firebreath

I used prep script to generate my first plugin project, build the plugin and create a symlink in ~/Library/Internet Plugins/(exactly as the mac tutorial videos show). Every time I start a browser(Firefox, Chrome or Safari) and then close it, Xcode always alerted me that "the project file "~.xcodeproj" is modified but was changed externally. Keep this version or read from disk?" 
I just can't figure out why?

Comment: What are you creating the symlink to?

Comment: a symlink in ~/Library/Internet Plugins/ to mysourcecode/build/projects/myplugin/Debug/myplugn.plugin.

Comment: I deleted the symlink and made a copy of my plugin bundle, but didn't solve the problem:(

Comment: No, not just browser.Every time i switch to ANY app and come back in XCode, the alert box show up. I've already compiled all the projects using the combined .xcodeproj file, so i'm using the plugin .xcodeproj file now. If i always using the combined one, the alert box never show up. i hope someone works with firebreath can explain the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first of all, just for clarity, this is either a cmake issue or an xcode issue, not a FireBreath issue.  I have never seen it happen before.  The main thing I would try is to delete the build/ directory entirely and then re-run the prep script (which just runs cmake) and see if the problem persists.

If it does, most likely it's something odd with your computer configuration, and specifically your xcode configuration.  :-/  I wish I could give you a better suggestion. You're also welcome to drop into the #firebreath IRC room at http://npapi.com/chat and we'll try to help you there.

Comment: I deleted the build/ directory and re-run the prep script but no luck.XCode is still annoying me. My Xcode is just installed and all configurations should be default. Could you give me any suggestions? or always use the combined project to compile my plugin bundle.

Comment: ? You mean you were using the build/projects/<project>/<project>.xcodeproject/ to build it?  If so, that's the issue. *Always* use FireBreath.xcodeproject/ (the combined project) to build.

Answer (score 0):

i flow firebreath [doc](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Building+on+Mac+OS+X), create a symlink of plugin to  ~/Library/Internet Plugins, but safari and firefox all not load the plugin.
but i cp the plugin package to  ~/Library/Internet Plugins, and all browsers work.